# How to assign the sending and receiving bubble layout without creating /passing user ID to offline SMS app in kotlin..?

Tags: android, kotlin

Since my app is offline and do not required user ID.I have to assign the bubble layout to sending and receiving SMS in offline SMS app, but I do not know how to do this.All the tutorials creating online app using user ID.Is there any way how to assign them in offline app..?

I have watched alot of blogs and tutorials.

```
 class MessageAdapter(val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder>(){companion object {
        const val VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT = 1
       const val VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2
    }



    private val messages: ArrayList<Message> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder {
        val view: View

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
          view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_message, parent, false)
            return MessageViewHolder(view)
        } else  {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.other_message, parent, false)
            return OtherMessageViewHolder(view)
        }

    }
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val message = messages.get(position)

        return if(App.user == message.user) {
            VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT
        }
        else {
            VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
        }
    }
}`
```

Expected:
I want to assign sending and receving layout without user ID.I do not created any App class too.

Actual:Its the online app code which extracting user creating account in App.

```
return if(App.user == message.user) {
            VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT
        }
        else {
            VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just trying to create a simple chat application , where one user sends and one user responds, but on the same app, you can do something like this :

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
  val messsage = messages[position]

   return if(message.isSending){
     VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT
    } else {
     VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED 
    }
```

then, in your message class, add:
`val isSending : Boolean.`

where you are creating these objects, you'll just simply have to decide if the user is sending or receiving and your layouts will be created based on this boolean.

if you changed your model class to `Messages`, you have to change: `private val messages: ArrayList<Messages> = ArrayList()`

Comment: I have applied this.But they show error that isSending is unresolved reference.On ALT+Enter ,I got two options "rename reference" and "create extension property Message.isSending".I have choose 2nd option and created property on top of the Adapter class.

Comment: private val Message.isSending: Boolean
    get() {return true}

Comment: data class Message (val isSending: Boolean,
                    var message:String,
                    var time:Long){
}

Comment: `data class Message (val isSending: Boolean, var message:String, var time:Long){ } ` is correct, use `message.isSending` in your code, like in my answer

Comment: `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val message = messages.get(position)

        holder.bind(message)
    }

    open inner class MessageViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
            private var messageText = view.txtMyMessage
            private var timeText = view.txtMyMessageTime
       open fun bind(message: Message){
         messageText.text = message.message
            timeText.text = fromMillisToTimeString(millis = message.time)
        }
    }`

Comment: `message.message` and `message.time` ,`message.isSending` require `bind(message:Messages)`..As I did this they are sort out but `holder.bind(message)` shows type error ..It require Messages but found Message

Comment: I have using now `data class Messages(val isSending: Boolean, var message:String, var time:Long){ }` for removing confusing..